# MouseLintener does not work

Tags: java

I am  learning the template method and delegation now. I do not understand what interface inheritance to the newClass, and then the newClass past its inside method to NextClass.

When I ran it, MouseLintener does not work.

Could you please teach me how to fix my codes?
Thank you!

```
public class KiteComponent extends JComponent{
private ArrayList<Kite> kites;
private Point mousePoint;
public KiteComponent() {
    kites = new ArrayList<Kite>();
    ColoredCompoundShape c = new ColoredCompoundShape();

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
       {
           mousePoint = e.getLocationOnScreen();
           for (Kite s: kites){
               if (s.contains(mousePoint))
               s.setColor(s.getColor());}
           repaint();
       } 
    });
}

public void add(Kite k){ kites.add(k);repaint();}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
   for (Kite s : kites){ s.drawInColor(g2); }
} 
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What's the question?

Comment: What does you program do (or supposed to do)?

Comment: [Lesson: Interfaces and Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/)

Comment: The initial color of a kite is set to red. Then click on it and make it change color to be blue.

Answer (score 0):

```
s.setColor(s.getColor())
```

Isn't this useless, it's setting the same color it already is... If you think that this actually isn't being called, print a line in your mouseClicked method to check if it's actually being called.